# Loop to execute in different dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have many dataframes with weekly data and whose names follow a sequence like this: df1, df2, df3...dfN.

The point is that I have to execute one function in all of these dataframes, so I would like to create a loop to apply the function to them. I understand that the best way would be to join all of them in a list and use lapply. However, my functions belong to a specific package that only works with dataframes.

Any solution? Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: When you join all of them in a list each element is still a dataframe so your function should still work when you apply it using `lapply`.

Comment: How did you create all these variables in the first place? Having variables with indexes in their names is a bad code smell in R. It would probably be better to store the data frames in a list and then you can apply whatever function you want to each element of the list. You really should provide a more specific [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can provide the best possible suggestion.

Comment: It might be helpful to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272.

Comment: Google search something like `R apply function to list of data frames` and many useful responses will come up. Applying functions to list elements is regarded as a basic skill in R programming.